# Can't get access from my site to Google Drive API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have a website that isn't allowed out of our network. We use some domain name to access to it from our company's network (say `desire.it.loc`). And now I need to upload some file to google drive from my site. As I got so far first I should do is to authenticate to google account. I created project at `google developers console`, got client_id, secret etc. And now I'm getting

```
Error: invalid_request
device_id and device_name are required for private IP: http://x.x.x.x:x
```

My php code:

```
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("limits");
$client->setDeveloperKey("<key goes here>");    
$client->setClientId('<id goes here>');
$client->setClientSecret('<secret goes here>');    
$client->setRedirectUri('http://x.x.x.x:x');
$client->setScopes(array('http://x.x.x.x:x'));    

if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}    

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {    
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}    

if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl(); // error goes here
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}    

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

    $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

    foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
        echo "Account: ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";
        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WebProperty: ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";

            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                    //  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;View: ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";
                }
            }
        }
    } // closes account summaries

}
print "<br><br><br>";
print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token'];
?>
```

I'm not the administrator of our web-server, so I guess it would be difficult for me to change some setting there. Can I fix it somehow without registering "fake domains" or something like this.

Comment: What are you doing that elicits that error message?

Comment: @pinoyyid added my code to the question

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: @pinoyyid `$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$client->setRedirectUri('http://x.x.x.x:x');** isn't allowed. You need a domain name such as dev.example.com. You can configure your /etc/hosts (or windows equivalent) to resolve dev.example.com to the ip address. The same domain name needs to be registered in the Google API Console.

Comment: I tried it `Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://limits.desire.it.loc/`

Comment: it doesn't like the .loc. try "foo.bar.com"

Comment: So it should be added the web-server settings? In my case it's nginx

Comment: unless your nginx is configured to reject non-configured URLs, you shouldn't need to touch it. Just add the mapping from foo.bar.com to the IP address in your local /etc/hosts and you're done. If you need this for many PC's, you'll need to set up a DNS record somewhere, either on an in house DNS server, or a public one depending on your network config. That should be a new question elsewhere on stackexchange tagged dns, nginx, hosts